# How to Modify TCAP as "end" instead of "continue" in JSS7

Tags: java, ss7

I am dealing RoutingInfoForSMRequest using  JSS7. But in response, its always sending "continue" in TCAP layer. How to set it "end"?

My Code below:

onSendRoutingInfoForSMRequest(SendRoutingInfoForSMRequest arg0) {

```
     MAPDialogSms mapdialog = arg0.getMAPDialog();

            
        logger.info("MAPDialogSms: " + mapdialog);
        logger.info("Recieved TCAP Message Type:" + mapdialog.getTCAPMessageType());
 
      

        IMSI imsi = this.MAPParameterFactory.createIMSI(String.valueOf(""12747474747474));
        ISDNAddressString VLR_Number = this.mapProvider.getMAPParameterFactory().createISDNAddressString(AddressNature.international_number, org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.map.api.primitives.NumberingPlan.ISDN, ""12737373737373); 
        
        logger.info("IMSI: " + imsi);
        logger.info("VMSC: " + params.Msc_GT);
        
        LocationInfoWithLMSI linfo = this.MAPParameterFactory.createLocationInfoWithLMSI(VLR_Number, null, null, false, null);
        mapdialog.addSendRoutingInfoForSMResponse(arg0.getInvokeId(), imsi, linfo, null, null, null);
        logger.info("IMSI MSISDN Link Session Time: " + params.imsi_msisdn_link_session + " sec");
        mapdialog.send();
        logger.info("Response sent");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :-)

Its simple.
mapdialog.close(false);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).